# Why can I access an object after its deinit method has been called?

Tags: swift, swift3, automatic-ref-counting

I copied most of this code from the **Unowned References** section in the Swift Guide and ran it in a playground...

```
class Customer {
    let name: String
    var card: CreditCard?

    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    deinit { print("\(name) is being “deinitialized") }
}

class CreditCard {
    let number: UInt64
    unowned let customer: Customer
    init(number: UInt64, customer: Customer) {
        self.number = number
        self.customer = customer
    }
    deinit { print("Card #\(number) is being deinitialized") }
}

var john: Customer?

john = Customer(name: "John Appleseed")
john!.card = CreditCard(number: 1234_5678_9012_3456, customer: john!)

var card = john!.card!

john = nil

card.customer.name
```

`john` set to `nil` results in...

> "John Appleseed is being “deinitialized\n"

But then getting the `name` property gives...

> "John Appleseed"

So, the customer instance is still accessible despite having being deinitialized!

Shouldn't this result in a nil reference exception? It says in the guide...

> Note also that Swift guarantees your app will crash if you try to
>   access an unowned reference after the instance it references is
>   deallocated. You will never encounter unexpected behavior in this
>   situation. Your app will always crash reliably, although you should,
>   of course, prevent it from doing so.

So, I presume it must not have been deallocated. And yet, the guide also says,

> A deinitializer is called immediately before a class instance is
>   deallocated.

Comment: Don't use a playground (they're super buggy & unreliable) – use a proper Swift environment like a full project. In a full project, this code crashes as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code works as expected in a regular project, as opposed to a playground.